# How do I create an archive with custom absolute paths?

Tags: linux, windows, archiving

I have a simple web app on Debian that I would like to distribute soon. For its update mechanism, I was hoping to take advantage of an archive's full path capability (such as RAR) by essentially having the app download the update and simply extract it. In theory, this should cleanly replace outdated files.

The problem I'm facing is there's no straightforward way (that I'm aware of) to create these absolute path archives on Windows for Linux, mainly because the `F:\ile\System` `/paths/are/different`.

Is there a compression tool on Windows that will let me manually specify the absolute path a file should take? I would like to specify that `home.html` should go to `/var/www/html/home.html` when extracted, for example.

Comment: tar? And why do you insist on absolute paths if you can go to / within installation script?

Comment: @tansy I'm leaning towards an installation/update script now that I've slept on the idea. Not only can I put any file anywhere, I can also do system maintenance and configuration with it. The question is now moot.